# Can't pass list items as session variables in php

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, html-lists, session-variables

I have an order page. I choose an item then add to the order list with javascript. The list can contain many items. I want to pass these items as session variables  into the order confirmation page.

Here is what I did;

This is javascript code to add items to the orderlist, there is no problem in that part. I append the selected item when button clicked.

```
$('#addToCartButton').click(function(){  

    var toAdd=$("#chooseItem option:selected").text();
    var itemNbr1=$("#itemNbr1").val();
    var cupSize=$("#cupSize option:selected").text();
    var milkType=$("#milkType option:selected").text();
    var cafein="";

    if ($("#cafein").is(':checked')==true){
        var cafein="Kafeinsiz";
    };

    if(toAdd !== defaultSelectFormText && itemNbr1 >=1){
        $('#defaultText').remove();            
        $('.orderList').append('<p id="items">' + itemNbr1 + ' Adet ' + cafein + ' ' + cupSize + ' ' + milkType + ' ' + toAdd + '<span class="extra">Sipariş listesinden çıkarmak için tıklayın!</span>' + '</p>');

    };
});
```

This is html part, when I push the firstConfirmButton it works, no problem. But in the php part I can't pass the items as session variables.

```
<form method="post" action="">
      <div class="col-md-5">
           <h3 align="center">Sipariş Listesi</h3>
           <ul class="orderList" name="orderList"></ul>
      </div>  
</form>

<form role="form" method="post" action="">
      <div id="firstConfirmButton">
          <button type="submit" name="firstConfirmButton" class="btn btn-  primary btn-lg">Onayla</button>
      </div>
</form>
```

This is php part, I saw "I'm here" . $_SESSION['FirstName'] part but $_SESSION['OrderList'] don't work;

```
<?php
    require("includes/db.php");
    require("includes/functions.php");

    session_start();

    if (isset($_POST['firstConfirmButton'])) { 

        $_SESSION['OrderList'] = $_POST['orderList'];
        echo "I'm here" . $_SESSION['FirstName'] . $_SESSION['OrderList'];

    }

?>
```

What is the problem, I stuck in that point.

Comment: So... are you attempting to post a `<ul>` as a form field? That isn't possible.

Comment: So, what should I do?

Comment: Change the UL to a form element e.g. input, select... whatever's best suited for its contents

Comment: well, I convert it to "label". It is form element right? But still it doesn't work. Here is the html code;                            <form method="post" action="">
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <h3 align="center">Sipariş Listesi</h3>
                            <label method="post" class="orderList" name="orderList"></label>
                        </div>  
                    </form>

Comment: what else element should I use for a shopping list? I also used textarea, but it doesn't work.